# Underlining Russian comments in VS code

Tags: c++

For me, VS code highlights comments written in Russian. It looks like this:

[What does it look like for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxhXG.png)

Comment: And what's your question? Looks like you have a spell checker that doesn't support russian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install russian anguage Pack for visual studio code.

Comment: I installed this extension, it now highlights part of the comments, and part does not. What to do?

Comment: Maybe the word is misspelled? Or unknown in plugin dictionary ?